# best way to enlarge system partition

Tags: partitioning

I have a problem - I need to enlarge my system partition. I mean - when I initially installed Ubuntu, I split the partition so I have 15GB for system and the rest (around 400) pointed at `/home/`. This is very useful if anything goes wrong someday and I want to format and completely re-install Ubuntu without losing any of my actual data.

The problem is, 15GB isn't enough, so it seems. I already moved `/var/` and `/opt/` folder to `/home/`, adding symlinks at root, but I'm still at 86% usage and I'm having performance issues (mostly when booting or running a VM).

I can use Ubuntu on a flash drive and externally enlarge the partition, but I'm really afraid with going forward with that plan. Also, despite what I said before, I'd like to avoid re-installing the system if at all possible. Any advice, suggestions or ideas on how to best approach this? Any warnings I should heed?

Thanks in advance!

**update**

[image]

Here's the gparted screenshot - as you can see, there's windows on dual boot (sda1-5 are all related to the windows system), then I have a linux swap, 14GB (so uh... not even 15) of system and 435 of for `/home`.

Comment: post the screenshot of your gparted partition editor.

Comment: @AvinashRaj There

Comment: "The problem is, 15GB isn't enough" I believe it is enough. My experience: you will see a perfomance hit when / is 95%+ full; not below 95%. Below it I would assume something else being the problem :) 1 thing I am missing: what is occupying those 13Gb? MySQL?  (if so: you can move the databases to /home/).. But besides that: you can create empty space IN FRONT OF /home with gparted and then add it to /.

Comment: @Rinzwind I have no idea what fills it up like that. One suspect I have is the VMWorkstation. I don't think it's MySQL since I think it keeps its data on `/var/`, and I moved that and replaced it with a symlink. Again - 86 is after I cleaned it up a little. I know there's a difference in performance because running ubuntu on a flash drive loads up and performs a lot better. I'm not sure this is the fault of the small space of the system, but I think It's a pretty logical assumption

Comment: I have a strong suspicion adding more free space to / you are going to run into trouble again. That free space will get used just like the other 11.44.  There is something wrong that fills your discs. 2 things: check for Trash directories and check /var/log/ for large log files.

Comment: @Rinzwind I emptied the trash, and `/var/log/` has no large log files (which is also irrelevant because `/var/` isn't physically on the system partition at all). I would agree with you, only it took a long time for it to fill up, it didn't happen overnight...

Comment: @Rinzwind it seems that `/usr/` occupies most of the space (8.3GB!). Though it mostly seems legit

Comment: @Rinzwind will it be safe to move `/usr/` to `/home/usr/` and add a symbolic link from root? The same way I did with `/var/`?

Comment: Yes but you are really messing up your filesystem like that ;) Another option: split /home into 3 parts and create mountpoints for /etc/ and /usr/?

Comment: @Rinzwind can you add an answer detailing the best way to proceed with that process? Should I do it through an external flash drive or is it ok to unmount `/home/`? (`/var/` is there but still...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To resize the size of your root partition (`/dev/sda8`), you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk or gparted live disk.
- After booting from live disk, make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda9` partition and select Resize move option. After that, a partition dialog box will appear.
- Move the left arrow to the right direction until you get the desired size for your root partition. Then select tick mark on the top and to save the changes made to the disk.
- Now the newly created unallocated space will be on the top of `/dev/sda9` partition. Finally you can be able to add the alllocated to your root (`/dev/sda8`) partition.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a step by step guide on how to manipulate partitions. I know that, and gparted's GUI is pretty straight forward. I was looking for a more detailed explanations about how best to approach this issue, if there are alternative solutions, and also suggestions from personal experience

Comment: I'm suggesting this from my personal experience. It must work. If you face any problem while following this answer then don't hesitate to ask me. Its the best approach for increasing the size of your root partition.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It worked smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following steps for you:

1. Restore all your system directories (var, opt) **back to the root partition sda8**.
2. Use **Ubuntu Live USB** (*GParted*) to **shrink your home partition
   sda9 to the right** by about say 20GB since you have plenty of disk
   space.
3. Use **[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) Live USB** to boot your computer, and **save your
   root partition sda8** just in case.
4. Use **Ubuntu Live USB** (*GParted*) again to **grow your root
   partition sda8 to the right** using the free space created earlier.

*Note: You can have both Ubuntu and Clonezilla Live on a single USB drive using **[MultiSystem](http://liveusb.info/)**.*